# Glide: How to achieve ScaleType.CENTER?

Tags: android, android-glide

The default transformations in Glide are: CenterCrop, CenterInside, CircleCrop, FitCenter, RoundedCorners.

How can I achieve the equivalent of ScaleType.**CENTER**?

- **CENTER**: Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

None of the Glide's default transformation does this, they are either cropping or scaling. I need the image to be drawn with its size, exactly how ScaleType.CENTER works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(this).load("").centerInside().into()
```

this should do the trick [check the docs](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/4140/library/com.bumptech.glide/-request-builder/index.html#-1152448165%2FFunctions%2F-954213597)

Updated1:
one more thing you can always set the scaletype you want in the xml on the image view and glide will respect that if you don't add one using it

Update ----
i have an idea load the image using glide then you set it manully
this way glide will only load the image for you i know it is Crud but check it

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load("")
            .listener( object :RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(
                    e: GlideException?,
                    model: Any?,
                    target: Target<Drawable>?,
                    isFirstResource: Boolean
                ): Boolean {
                    //loading failed
                    TODO("Not yet implemented")
                }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Drawable?,
                model: Any?,
                target: Target<Drawable>?,
                dataSource: DataSource?,
                isFirstResource: Boolean
            ): Boolean {
                //loading sucess
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

        }).submit()
```

Comment: `centerInside()` doesn't work. It scales the image keeping the aspect ratio.

Comment: I need Glide to draw the image exactly how ScaleType.CENTER works: Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling. It draws the image with its actual size, no matter what the size is.

Comment: val CENTER_INSIDE: DownsampleStrategy

Identical to FIT_CENTER, but never upscales. this is what it si said in the document [link](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/4140/library/com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap/-downsample-strategy/-c-e-n-t-e-r_-i-n-s-i-d-e.html) i think what you are seeing is glide resizing the image to scale it down to the size of the imageview i can't be sure

Comment: I have a simple layout for testing, with a RelativeLayout and two ImageView inside, both with `android:layout_width="match_parent"`, `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:scaleType="center"`, one using the image from drawable folder, the other one is using Glide with the exact code you posted, loading the same image from an URL. The ImageView which uses Glide scales down the image.

Comment: did you try to remove centerinside and let the image viewhandle the scaling as i am not seeing anything in the docs similer to Center only

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The image is drawn filling the ImageView, so the ScaleType.CENTER is ignored. I also tried adding `noTransform()` with the same result.

Comment: did you try to load the image from the resources file with glide did it has the same scalling

Comment: Yes, same result, it fills the ImageView instead of respecting `android:scaleType="center"` and center the image. I also tried to add `dontTransform()` and `dontAnimate()`, no luck.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion with using the listener and it still fills the ImageView. But I noticed something interesting. The `Drawable` in the `resource` parameter in the `onResourceReady` has the bitmap with much bigger size than the actual image. So Glide doesn't just download the  image and load it to a Drawable, it does more than that.

Comment: I noticed the Density is also different.

Comment: made some progress with `.apply(RequestOptions.overrideOf(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL))` as described in https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/779. 
 It centers the image, but its size is incorrect, it's smaller than what it should be (compared to using an `ImageView` which has `android:src=` set to a image in resources obtained from downloading from the same Uri). I tried to use a listener and set the density correctly as described in https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/672 but it didn't work, the image is still small...

Comment: are you sure of the image you download i feel something off

Comment: Yes. You can try it too, it should take about 5 mins to put together a quick sample.